# How to make only first element visible in ng-repeat after it loads into DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working ng-repeat in angular js and i am not getting exact solution for below :

```
<div class="some">
    <ul style="list-style:none">
        <li ng-repeat="loopMe in data"><span id="step{{$index+1}}" style="display:none">{{loopMe}}</span></li>
     </ul>
</div>

**AJAX Call**
$http({
method: 'GET',
url: 'data.json',
}).success(function (data,status) {
    $scope.data = data
    document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';

}
```

I want to make first element to get displayed just after the data is received.
But the problem is as data is received ng-repeat did not finishes and

`document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';` gives **error** that **Cannot read property 'style' of null**

But when i give timeout like

```
 $timeout(function () { 
    document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';
 }, 1000);
```

It worked, but i need other way around which can work just after the ng-repeat  loads all the li into the DOM.

P.S - I am using angular 1.5

Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, you should think about your business logic and data first, and then page markup or style. Currently you have steps in your $scope.data, and I understand that you want to display step one. So what you can do is to add another variable to your scope which will indicate current step.

```
<div class="some">
    <ul style="list-style:none">
        <li ng-repeat="loopMe in data"><span ng-hide="$index!=currentStep">{{loopMe}}</span></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

and in $http handler,

```
$http({
method: 'GET',
url: 'data.json',
}).success(function (data,status) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.currentStep=1;

}
```

Comment: This one worked for me , nice and best i think for my case..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do it from the view, dont use jquery, you can do with **[limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)** filter

```
 <li ng-repeat="loopMe in data |  limitTo: 1">
```

Comment: But all the elements are being shown when i used 
<li ng-repeat="loopMe in data"><span id="step{{$index+1}}" |  limitTo: 1>{{loopMe}}</span></li>

Comment: can you create a plunker

Answer (score 2):

There is some default properties of ng-repeat. Like $index, $first, $middle and some others. Using $first property you can get your desired output.

```
 <li ng-repeat="loopMe in data"><span id="step{{$index+1}}" ng-style="$first ? { 'display':'block' } : { 'display': 'none' }">{{loopMe}}</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just css.

```
.some ul li {display: none;}
.some ul li:first-child {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="some">
  <ul style="list-style:none">
    <li ng-repeat="loopMe in data">
      <span id="step{{$index+1}}" ng-style="$index == 0 ? { 'display':'block' } : { 'display': 'none' }"> {{loopMe}} </span></li>
 </ul>
```

Use ng-style with condition.

Comment: Is it useful for you

Comment: for me @SSH answer worked for my scenario but thanks for your inputs!!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `ng-repeat` special property called `$first`

**HTML**

```
<div class="some">
    <ul style="list-style:none">
        <li ng-repeat="loopMe in data"><span id="step{{$index+1}}" ng-class="{'hideSpan': !$first}">{{loopMe}}</span></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hideSpan{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way, because all other data gets rendered into DOM but not displayed. The best way is to limit the output of ng-repeat using limitTo

Comment: @kvetis this is and example of how to use `$first` property to achieve what was needed. You could also use this property with ng-if `<li ng-repeat="loopMe in data" ng-if="$first">` which won't render unnecessary `li` element. There are many ways to do it and mine is just one of them.

Comment: After I studied a bit more what the question was about, I must admit that your solution is what was asked for - to show the span element only if it was the first repeated item. It's more clear from the selected answer, that the `li` element will contain more data that should be shown.

Answer (score -1):

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
   document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';
});
```

Use can use this too (y)

Comment: Accessing DOM is completely unnecessary and should be avoided and used only in directives.